# php application fail with Apache server (Wordpress, phpMyAdmin and Squirrrelmail)

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, phpmyadmin

Yesterday my Apache installation stopped working with PHP applications like Wordpress, phpMyAdmin and Squirrelmail.

The problem is that Apache-php chokes on lines containing the "global" statement.

The Wordpress error looks like this:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$error' (T_VARIABLE) in /var/www/html/XXXXXXX/wordpress/wp-login.php on line 34
```

Line 34 contains the "global" statement:

```
  global $error, $interim_login, $action;
```

Similar in phpMyAdmin:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '$text_domains' (T_VARIABLE) in /usr/share/php/gettext/gettext.inc on line 47
```

Line 47 also includes the global statement:

```
global $text_domains, $default_domain, $LC_CATEGORIES, $EMULATEGETTEXT, $CURRENTLOCALE;
```

If I comment out the line PHP just fails on the next line including the "globa"l statement.

I tried to execute the file using php command line and it finishes without any error.

The latest software upgrades doesn't seem to be related.

iwl100-firmware

iwl1000-firmware

iwl105-firmware

iwl135-firmware

iwl2000-firmware

iwl2030-firmware

iwl3160-firmware

iwl3945-firmware

iwl4965-firmware

iwl5000-firmware

iwl5150-firmware

iwl6000-firmware

iwl6000g2a-firmware

iwl6000g2b-firmware

iwl6050-firmware

iwl7260-firmware

libappstream-glib

libertas-usb8388-firmware

linux-firmware

opus

rpcbind

tzdata

tzdata-java

webkitgtk4

webkitgtk4-jsc

webkitgtk4-plugin-process-gtk2

Hoping that someone has a clue.

Thanks
John

Comment: your description says as if this was an "Apache" problem but all you are showing are PHP parsing errors. Check your php installation instead. Loading a third party module in apache to parse php content does not make it an "apache" issue, all php parsing is done through php software, You should check that instead.

Comment: I mention Apache as it only fails with Apache. Executing the files with php does not report any errors.

Comment: The problem seems to be solved by upgrading the system from Fedora 24 to Fedora 25.